# set auto grid slide in jquery.gridnav.js

Tags: jquery, gridview

http://tympanus.net/Development/GridNavigationEffects/example10.html

http://tympanus.net/Development/GridNavigationEffects/js/jquery.gridnav.js

I want same effect for grid slide but to see that effect we have to click on previous & next icon but I want it automatically after page load.

Also, when we reach last row it should start again from first slide automatically.

Comment: Didn't get you would you provide more info

Comment: On the first link, there is effect for grid to slide up & slide which will display after clicking on previous, next icon..this effect will work only when I click on that prev/next icon. Instead of that I want it automatically(no need to click on that icons) when page load. Also, the last slide reach it should append the first slide again. Means it play continuously. the second link is the JS file they have used for this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take one question at a time

For the first part you want to work it automatically, So you can do one thing, Programatically call click event on the next button.(You can also hide the button with css if you don't want it to visible to users)
This is the code for that

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#tj_next').trigger('click'); 
    }, 2000);// Every 2000 miliseconds, i.e. 2 seconds it will show next page
});
```

Here you can pass id of the next and previous clicks with settings aswell, by default it is 'tj_next'

If you want to call it periodically then you can use window.setTimeout for that aswell

Comment: it works by clicking on next or previous button but this should happen automatically once page load. It should not  need to click on any button.

Comment: That is what I have explained, You need to trigger this in your code, I have updated code for more clarity

Comment: ok..but what about it should start from first slide after it reaches to last slide

Comment: I'm afraid that is not supported by library code, probably you need to change that code in gridnav library... Otherwise there is one possible hack for this which might work, When you navigate through next page, remove first 'li' elements and append it to the div again at last... this may work